# Syncing source code between two computers

Tags: workflow

I have two computers for development, and I often have to switch to my notebook from desktop before I have anything commit-worthy. Which way is considered best practice for syncing?

Comment: Why not work in a git branch?

Comment: Is it a good practice though? When merging, everyone will see these useless commits, right?

Comment: You could 'squash' your commits into one if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vincent Driessen's gitflow workflow allows developers on larger projects to work on feature branches that can be merged into the 'develop' branch on a regular basis. This is a well-established way to work with git. http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/